# Text Color in TextBox is Grey in IE9 BUT Not in Mozilla

Tags: css, stylesheet

In my table:

```
<table class ="test">
              <tr class="bill">
                    <td class="total-title">Totals</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="Test1" type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="Test2" type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="Test3" type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </td>
              </tr>
```

The color of the text inside the textbox is GREY in IE9 but not in Mozilla. 
**What should be the sytle for ONLY TextBox value? I know my all 'td' classes are different, but thats the requirement.**

---

I did this:

```
.Tax #MyPage TABLE.test INPUT[disabled='disabled'] 
 { 
    color: #CCC; 
 }
```

Not working :(

Comment: What color do you want it to be? If you don't declare your own styles, or baseline them with a css reset, they'll be whatever the browser default is for disabled, readonly text inputs. Which, as you see, can vary across browsers.

Comment: Or are you asking how to declare the `color` for an input value?

Comment: That's just because IE sucks.

Comment: @OlexandrSkrypnyk: Thats right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grey text is because of IE9's built-in styles and it decides to color it like so. Other browsers can treat disabled items all a bit differently.

If you want finer control over the style in all browsers, you might want to look into CSS Attribute Selectors to see if that will help. May have to throw an !important in there, but not sure on that.

```
input[disabled='disabled']
{
color: #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the attribute selector. You can do that like this.

```
input[type=text] { color:grey; }
```